# Incorporate existing AWS resources into a CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to incorporate existing AWS resources that were created outside of CloudFormation into an existing CloudFormation stack? I'd like to do this without having to add a new resource in the CloudFormation stack and migrate the existing resource's data over to that new resource. I see that AWS now has drift detection for CloudFormation stacks. I'm wondering if that might be able to be leveraged to incorporate existing resources into a stack.

Answer (score 14):

The ability to import/adopt resources into an existing CloudFormation stack is the #1 ask from CloudFormation customers. We've been thinking about ways to do it for a while, but haven't hit upon the mechanism that both fits customer needs and works at the scale the service operates.

Since we don't expose stack state info anywhere outside the service for you to modify, the only approach you can take until we offer an adoption feature is to either store metadata about the resources in a parameter store, or use a custom resource as a wrapper to retrieve the information about the underlying resource and then surface it to your stack via Fn::GetAtt.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Now you finally can do it with Resource Import feature, references:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

https://twitter.com/shortjared/status/1193985448164691970?s=21

Comment: Can you provide a simple example? I've tried doing through CloudFormation on AWS Console but it looks like you still need to import a template or provide an s3 url.

Comment: @TrieuNomad try using it conjunction with https://former2.com

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by passing existing resource information to your stack via [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html). [Here is an example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/passing-parameters-to-cloudformation-stacks-with-the-aws-cli-and-powershell/) of how to pass these parameters to the stack.

Check out [this blog post](https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-cloudformation-optional-resources/) from Eric Hammond describing how you can incorporate these parameters into the rest of the stack. The use-case described is a bit different in that they are optionally creating new resources if they aren't passed in, but the overall structure applies to the case you've described.

In this case I don't think Drift Detection will help you, since it will show differences between deployed resources and the configuration described in a stack. Resources defined/created outside of the stack won't be checked.

Comment: I saw that blog post, and correct me if I'm wrong here, but I believe that involves conditional creation of the resource, but not full *incorporation* of the resource into the cloudformation stack, right? I'd like the cloudformation stack to completely assume/take over the AWS resource and have it managed there. It doesn't look like that is fully possible currently with AWS.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I understood your question to mean that you want to reference existing resources but not define them in the stack. As far as I know there is no way to delegate configuration of an existing resource to cloudformation without rebuilding it.

Answer (score 3):

[Amazons CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/CDK/latest/userguide/what-is.html) (currently in the stage of developer preview as of writing) offers a way to do that:

> If you need to reference a resource, such as an Amazon S3 bucket or VPC, that's defined outside of your CDK app, you can use the Xxxx.import(...) static methods that are available on AWS constructs. For example, you can use the Bucket.import() method to obtain a BucketRef object, which can be used in most places where a bucket is required. This pattern enables treating resources defined outside of your app as if they are part of your app.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/CDK/latest/userguide/aws_construct_lib.html

It also allows to import existing CloudFormation templates:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/CDK/latest/userguide/use_cfn_template.html

Answer (score 2):

Importing existing resources to stacks is now supported by CloudFormation :

Announcement from AWS : [AWS CloudFormation Launches Resource Import](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-cloudformation-launches-resource-import)

Instructions Via an example : [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Cloudformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) might help you to create a new stack from existing resources and then you can add more resources to the stack. But don't know of a way to "merge" an existing stack with existing resources outside the stack.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into that, but I really don't want to go the way of creating a new stack. For now, I can keep going the way I have been with managing some resources outside of the stack, but I was curious if there was a way at this point to merge those into the existing stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I needed to import an ARN value from an existing SAM output in my account, so that I could add the proper invoke policy in my new stack.

I was looking for an equivalent of SAM's `Fn::ImportValue`, and found out that the core module has a static `Fn.importValue` method you can use as such:

```js
const cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
const lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda')

class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // The below line did the trick
        const arn = cdk.Fn.importValue(`your-sam-function-export-name`)
        const myLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this, 'myLambda', arn)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Fn.html