# How to do infrastructure code on existing services built from the console?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

Growing and going fast, we have created some AWS services from the panel, but now we need to go back and get them under CloudFormation. I am looking for some direction on how to get these existing items in CloudFormation. As a simple example, we have a security group that has been created from the panel and other services are using the security group ID. So, there is no CloudFormation to modify going forward when we need to make changes. How can I do a CloudFormation template for this security group without creating a new security group/security group ID and get it to show in CloudFormation so we can manage it with code going forward? Now, I am using this security group in this question as an example to understand how to approach this conceptually. I will want to do this for other services too like RDS, Fargate, S3, etc... following a model of creating from the panel and then follow up and put code in place to support it. I am not looking for answers to deal with the security group example - currently, we just manage the rules in CF for that and use a sg ID to apply them. I hope my ask is clear and thanks for any direction you may have to offer.

The security group used in the example is a real situation where we could not find a way to put CloudFormation in place behind the existing security group. We are dealing with that specific situation by just having a CloudFormation template with a security group ID as a parameter and managing the rules for the security group in SCM.

I am looking for a way of creating from the panel and then follow up and put code in place to support it without impacting the existing services/ID's.

Comment: What does this have to do with Terraform?

Comment: The example is CloudFormation, but the ask is to understand ways to put infrastructure code in place for existing services that were created in the console. I have heard that Terraform may do this. I am trying to dive into it this week and understand it's behavior and what it can offer. I am not limited to CloudFormation.

Comment: You should probably make the question clearer that you are looking for infrastructure as code tools for this and are specifically looking at CloudFormation and Terraform then. Terraform will let you do this via data sources and/or importing depending on your use case/requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to bring existing resources into a CloudFormation stack (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450440/715780)

You will need to use a strategy of creating new resources via CloudFormation and migrate away from your existing resources. This will be easier for some things (like Auto scaling group or VPCs) and more difficult and possibly not worthwhile for others (like a Dynamo table with important data).

I've never used CloudFormer, but you may find it useful to generate templates from your existing resources (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)

You may find CDK easier to work with than writing your own CloudFormation. It has the benefit that it can reference existing resources (possibly useful during migration) and import any CF templates you've already written or generated using CloudFormer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297703/715780).

Answer (score 1):

As original accepted answer suggested - there is CloudFormation feature or resource adoption/import in the works. I'm happy to report that this has been released as of yesterday, and is ready for consumption - it is possible to import existing AWS Resources into CFN stacks. You can [read more about concepts and mechanics of it on official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)