# Serverless getting VPC id from vpc declaration

Tags: serverless-framework

In my provider: block I have a VPC declared as vpc:

How can I get the id/ARN/whatever of this VPC in my resources block? I have an AWS CloudFormation resource and I want to pass my VPC's id as the VpcId. Is there some ${self:} thing to get the id?

I tried Ref: vpc but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to use `Ref` as the resource wasn't created within this stack.

By setting `vpc` configuration in either the `functions` or `provider` block you're referencing existing resources.

If the existing resource was created using CloudFormation you could [export it and make it available for import](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/cross-stack-references-in-serverless.html) in this stack, but if it was [created manually its not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450440/1748964).